# How can I change my horse's equipment?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I've just bought a new bridle and saddle from the fang and bone store, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to equip them. Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer literally minutes after asking. You need to be riding the horse at a stable and speak to the girl tending the horses. If your affection is high enough she allows you to change your gear and mane.